# Get static FIELD value using annotation processing

Tags: java, android, annotations, apt, annotation-processing

It sounds like a simple question, but I cannot manage to make it work in Android.

What Ive got is a simple annotated field:

```
@MyAnnotation
public static final String TEXT = getText();

private static final String getText(){
    return "TEXT";
}
```

I made an annotation processer to process `@MyAnnotation`, but I found out that it is not possible to **read value** of field using annotation processor. I have also tried `reflection`, but **reflection is only available at runtime** ..

I need that field value for code generation based on it.

It is possible to read value of field using annotation processing ? If not is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor{
 ...
 @Override
 public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
      // Only one annotation, so just use annotations.iterator().next();
    Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotations.iterator().next());
    Set<VariableElement> fields = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(elements);
    for (VariableElement field : fields) {
        field.getConstantValue();  //get the value of static field?
    }
    return true;
 }
 ...
}
```

the method `getConstantValue()` may help you.

> Returns the value of this variable if this is a {@code final}
>    field initialized to a compile-time constant.